# alert dialog does not work for button click function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add two actions in one button click, one handle form post another to show alert , the one for post works but the one to show alert doesn't .and when i try another action inside this button click does not work too

```
  $('plot_marker').click(function () {
    $.post('/searched/', $('mapform').serialize(), function (data) {

        },
        'json' // I expect a JSON response
    );
    alert("Hello!");

});
```

Comment: Errors in the console?

Comment: The above code is really only `$('plot_marker').click(function () { alert("hello"); }`, the Ajax request is irrelevant. Was that your intention?

Comment: `$('plot_marker')` won't select anything. There is no tagname `plot_marker`. Add `.` if it is a classname or `#` if it is an ID.

Comment: `$('mapform').serialize()` doesnt make sense. Either `.mapForm` or `#mapForm`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Not necessarily true, `plot_marker` [is a tag selector](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/). Polymer?

Comment: @msanford the link you gave doen't prove it. Another link maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using Web Components or some other framework, you almost certainly meant `$('#plot_marker')` or `$('.plot_marker')`.

In your sample code you have used the [is a tag selector](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) which is a valid query selector used for selecting tags by name, but that was likely not your original intent.

Comment: What happened to the _"not necessarly true"_?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It became "almost certainly", phrased so as not to require additional details from the asker so it doesn't get trashed in review ;) My point in the comment above was merely that asserting that query selectors *must always* begin with `#` or `.` is not correct, and I explained the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, unless 'plot_marker' is a tag name, it should either be '#plot_marker' or '.plot_marker' depending on whether it is an id or a class.

```
$('plot_marker').click(function () {
    $.post('/searched/', $('mapform').serialize(), function (data) {

        },
        'json' // I expect a JSON response
    );
    alert("Hello!");

});
```

Comment: No you do not always need to. OP's query selector is valid, called the [tag selector](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/); they just probably didn't *intend to use that selector*.

Comment: @msanford Yes, I agree. I should have been more explicit with my answer. I assumed that plot_marker is not a tag. Edited my answer to avoid confusion.